# Iterate on object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have an object like this :

```
 obj: {
        'tags': {
                '0': 'One',
                '1': 'Two',
                '2': 'Three',
                '3': 'Four',
                '4': 'Five',
                '5': 'Six',
                }
```

I do this :

```
<div
    v-for="(tag, index) in obj.tags">
    <v-text-field
     v-model="tag"

    >
    </v-text-field>
</div>
```

I want to display the value in a vuetify text field but when I do a vfor I have this message :

```
<v-text-field v-model="tag">: You are binding v-model directly to a v-for iteration alias. This will not be able to modify the v-for source array because writing to the alias is like modifying a function local variable. Consider using an array of objects and use v-model on an object property instead.
```

How can I do ?

Comment: Can you not transform that object into an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because tag is an 'Alias' of the Object you are using, we cannot reference it by that alias.

We can however, rebind it to the original object, using the index from v-for.

This will bind it for you.

```
<v-text-field v-model="obj.tags[index]">    
</v-text-field>
```

Comment: that doesn't work, also I need to have a v-model if possible, because I have to edit name after

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood the question but I think I know what you mean now. Let me look into it for you :)